# Python pptx merging table rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-pptx

I have a table in powerpoint where (after rendering with some other function) every other row remains completely empty. I tried solving that by merging every empty row with the row below it, as follows:

```
def is_empty_row(row):
       for cell in row.cells:
           if len(cell.text):
               return False
    return True

def merge_empty_row(table,index): # Assumes no 2 consecutive rows are empty!
    row = table.rows[index]
    try:
        next_row = table.rows[index+1]
    except:
        return
    cell_1 = row.cells[0]
    cell_2 = next_row.cells[len(next_row.cells)-1]
    cell_1.merge(cell_2)

def fix_tables(document):
    ppt = Presentation(document)
    for slide in ppt.slides:
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            if shape.shape_type == MSO_SHAPE_TYPE.TABLE:
                for index in range(len(shape.table.rows)):
                    if is_empty_row(shape.table.rows[index]):
                        merge_empty_row(shape.table, index)
    docname = "".join(document.split(".")[0])
    ppt.save(docname+'.out.pptx')
```

And I am calling this function from Django on a template pptx file, only to get the following error:

```
Exception Type: XMLSyntaxError at /amas/analysis/1178/report/download/34
Exception Value: Opening and ending tag mismatch: r line 2 and t, line 2, column 11532 (<string>, line 2)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My first choice would be avoiding inserting empty rows. But if that weren't possible for some reason you could try deleting empty rows like this:

```
def delete_row(row):
    tr = row._tr
    tr.getparent().remove(tr)

rows = [table.rows[i] for i in range(len(rows))]
empty_rows = [r for r in rows if row_is_empty(r)]
for row in empty_rows:
    delete_row(row)
```

You need to identify the empty rows separately beforehand because otherwise deleting them in the middle of iteration can screw up the references (change which row `rows[i]` points to).

Comment: Weirdly enough, the error still remains unchanged with this code. I’ve managed to avoid inserting empty rows (almost) always, so I think I am good to go. Thanks for the response!